# Delete everything after a number of characters in string in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

The following is an example of characters per line in Notepad ++. I need to limit the characters per line to 14 characters.

> 11111111111111111111
>   222222222222222222222222222
>   33333333333333333333333

I need it to look like the following:

> 11111111111111
>   22222222222222
>   33333333333333

How can I can limit the number of characters to 14 characters per line in Notepad++

Comment: Can you please provide more information on the root goal you are trying to accomplish - is this just for editting or will the file be used by another system and need it this way, is it arbitrary characters or specific patterns?

Comment: If you only need to do it once, take a look at the Column Mode feature http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html and just delete the 13 last ones with a few clicks.

Answer (score 5):

Do a Regex replace.
Replace `^(.{14}).*$` with `\1`. Keep the `. matches newline` option unchecked.

Comment: For some reason I have noted that the ^ character doesn't always work in Notepad++, it can't find a regex starting with it. Any idea as to why?

Comment: It worked for me with OP's sample data. Can you post your sample on pastebin?

Comment: It was on another similar question, where the OP needed to remove all occurences of literal "\N" on each line except the first. So I suggested he run `(\\N.*?)\\N` multiple times. It worked, but another user posted this `^(.*?\\N.*?)\\N` (when we thought the OP only wanted to remove the second occurence on each line) which did not work for the asker, nor for me. Notepad++ was simply unable to find it. No issues with your redex, though...

Answer (score 1):

In notepad++ you can use the find and replace function like this : 
[image]

Comment: You might want to add ^ and & to it just to make it fail safe and OP has mentioned characters. Its not just digits.